# Share ARSCNView from iOS to SCNView on macOS wirelessly

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Is there a way to wirelessly share ARSCNView in iOS to SCNView (or to NSView) on macOS?

I need to share it programmatically. And I don't need a wireless screen-mirroring applications like Reflector.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If it is a static scene, you can use multi peer connectivity to share the point of view position with the computer